# What is the best way to rebuild a PDDocument(from PDFBox)?

Tags: java, pdfbox, serializable, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a PDDocument object on a WAS and it needs to be transmitted to a client server to be used there. 
The pddocument is not serializable so I have to find another solution to get it there.
I am now thinking of doing this:
1. On the WAS: saving the PDDocument to a ByteArrayOutputStream and passing that outputstream to the client server.
Like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
document.close();
```

2. And on the client server: reading in the passed outputstream with the load() method of PDDocument.
So:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

Is this a good solution or are their better ways to do this?

Comment: *"Is this a good solution"* - yes, it is. At least there is no universally better one. You don't mention, though, why you explicitly want to transfer a `PDDocument` object instead of simply a pdf file, so I don't know whether doing this will cause you any trouble.